# Veem ou vêem: qual a forma correcta dos verbos ‘ver’, ou ‘ler’ no presente do indicativo da terceira pessoa do plural?

Tags: ortografia, conjugações

Encontram-se ambas as formas do verbo ver no presente do indicativo da terceira pessoa do plural:

> Eles vêem a paisagem
>   Eles veem a paisagem

O mesmo acontece com o verbo ‘ler’: ‘Elas lêem à noite’, ou ‘Elas leem à noite’.

São ambas correctas? São diferentes ortografias entre Portugal e o Brasil?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I. Na nova grafia escreve-se:

- ver, eles v**ee**m;
- ler, eles l**ee**m;

mas

- ter, eles têm;
- vir, eles vêm.

Na antiga grafia escrevia-se:

- ver, eles vêem;
- ler, eles lêem;
- ter, eles têm;
- vir, eles vêm.

II. As formas *veem* e *leem* escrevem-se da mesma maneira em ambas as versões do português ([conjugador FLiP On-line](http://www.flip.pt/flip-on-line/conjugador.aspx)).

--

Referência: Dicionário de verbos portugueses, Texto Editora, Alfragide, Portugal, 2011.

Comment: Muito obrigado, já estou fora do sufoco do português mal falado.

Comment: @soarescastro De nada!

Answer (score 2):

As [formas corretas eram](http://emportuguescorrecto.blogs.sapo.pt/17125.html) *vêem* e *lêem*, antes do novo acordo ortográfico. Contudo, [agora são corretas](http://www.mundoeducacao.com/gramatica/vem-vem-veem.htm) [[1]](http://revistaescola.abril.com.br/lingua-portuguesa/pratica-pedagogica/acento-circunflexo-425777.shtml) *veem* e *leem*.