# Terceira pessoa do plural, no presente do indicativo, do verbo ter

Tags: pronúncia, diferenças, conjugações

Há uma diferença de pronúncia entre Brasil e Portugal, quando se fala o verbo **ter** no presente do indicativo, usando a terceira pessoa do plural:

```
Os homens têm os pássaros.
```

Em Portugal, sempre oiço o `têm` acima como "têem". Daí, surgiram-me algumas questões: Escrevia-se "têem" antigamente? Se sim, quando passaram a escrever "têm"?

Comment: Depende do ponto de vista, suponho eu. :) `No Brasil, sempre ouvi dizerem "têm" como "tem". Será que se escrevia "tem" antigamente? Se sim, quando passaram a escrever "têm"?` Mais seriamente: encontrei uma pergunta com alguma informação relacionada, que pode ajudar a estabelecer uma resposta - http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/476/veem-ou-v%C3%AAem-qual-a-forma-correcta-dos-verbos-ver-ou-ler-no-presente-do-in?rq=1

Comment: Acredito que "teem" sem acento, foi posteriormente transformado em "têm".  Agora, com o Acordo Ortográfico acho que o acento foi eliminado.  Alguém sabe ao certo?

Comment: Não creio que alguma vez se tenha escrito *teem* ou *têem*. A pronúncia tem variado ao longo do tempo e varia regionalmente, mesmo num país pequeno como Portugal. Felipe, deves ter também reparado que em Portugal, pelo menos o pessoal do sul, diz *tanho* (tenho) e *vanho* (venho), mas estas palavras nunca se escreveram com ***a***. E na verdade, tal como *têm* é pronunciado no sul de Portugal, até se poderia escrever *tãeem*. O verbo ter não foi afetado pelo AO: *ele tem, eles têm*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A alteração deu-se no acordo ortográfico de 1945 ([Conclusões complementares do Acordo de 1931 - Segunda Parte, ponto 20](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/?action=acordo&version=1945)) [o acordo de 1931 só entrou em vigor como parte do de 1945]:

> Emprego do acento circunflexo nas formas da terceira pessoa do plural *têm, vêm, contêm, convêm*, etc., graficamente distintas das terceiras pessoas do singular correspondente - *tem, vem, contém, convém*, etc. Essas formas terão emprego exclusivo na escrita corrente, preterindo assim as flexões *têem, contêem, convêem,* etc. que se consideram como dialectais.

Já agora, a pronúncia padrão em Portugal é [ˈtɐ̃j̃ɐ̃j̃]. Portanto "vêm" e "veem" não são homófonas (a última pronuncia-se [ˈveɐ̃j̃]).

Comment: Está esclarecido. Encontrei [um texto](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dDM9AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA379&lpg=PA379&dq=%22t%C3%AAem%22+antigo&source=bl&ots=6peV9qK3LW&sig=01t3dWgBfHqJzGWIEpzAlFSJPPI&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiwsLztwq7JAhXMAxoKHRdXBS4Q6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22t%C3%AAem%22%20antigo&f=false) de 1839 em que é possível se ler "têem".

Comment: Ando a ler a 1ª edição do *Sem Remédio* do Abel Botelho, 1900, e não me lembro de ver o raio do *têem*. Já devo tar tão habituado à grafia da época, que nem noto.

Comment: Na minha opinião, a grafia de "vêm" deveria ser ⟨vẽem⟩ (com dois e's e um til), pois é basicamente uma vogal /e/ nasal seguida de outra vogal /e/ nasal (que em portugal é realizado como `[ɐ̃j̃]`); daí as qualidades nasais seriam indicadas pelo til e pelo ⟨-m⟩, respectivamente. Enquanto "veem" continuaria ⟨veem⟩, já que só o segundo /e/ é nasal.